# Matplotlib slow when plotting pre-cached data into many subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Although there are many matplotlib optimization posts around, I didn't find the exact tips I want here, such as:
[Matplotlib slow with large data sets, how to enable decimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752915/matplotlib-slow-with-large-data-sets-how-to-enable-decimation)

[Matplotlib - Fast way to create many subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954925/matplotlib-fast-way-to-create-many-subplots)

My problem is that I have cached CSV files of time-series data (40 of them).
I'd like to plot them in one plot with 40 subplots in a vertical series, and output them to a single rasterized image.

My code using matplotlib is as follows:

```
def _Draw(self):
    """Output a graph of subplots."""
    BigFont = 10
    # Prepare subplots.
    nFiles = len(self.inFiles)
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.axis('off')
    for i, f in enumerate(self.inFiles[0:3]):
        pltTitle = '{}:{}'.format(i, f)
        colorFile = self._GenerateOutpath(f, '_rgb.csv')
        data = np.loadtxt(colorFile, delimiter=Separator)
        nRows = data.shape[0]
        ind = np.arange(nRows)
        vals = np.ones((nRows, 1))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(nFiles, 1, i+1)
        ax.set_title(pltTitle, fontsize=BigFont, loc='left')
        ax.axis('off')
        ax.bar(ind, vals, width=1.0, edgecolor='none', color=data)
    figout = plt.gcf()
    plt.savefig(self.args.outFile, dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

The script hangs for the whole night. On average my data are all ~10,000 x 3 to ~30,000 x 3 matrix.

In my case, I don't think I can use memmapfile to avoid memory hog because the subplot seems to be the problem here, not the data imported each loop.

I have no idea where to start to optimize this workflow.
I could, however, forget about subplots and generate one plot image per data at a time, and stitch the 40 images later, but that is not ideal.

Is there an easy way in matplotlib to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the way you're plotting your data.

Using `bar` to plot tens of thousands of bars of exactly the same size is *very* inefficient compared to using `imshow` to accomplish the same thing.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Random r,g,b data similar to what you seem to be loading in....
data = np.random.random((30000, 3))

# Make data a 1 x size x 3 array
data = data[None, ...]

# Plotting using `imshow` instead of `bar` will be _much_ faster.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This should be essentially equivalent to what you're currently doing, but will draw much faster and use less memory.

Comment: Aha, that was it! Thanks so much!